# send_message not sending message for pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot, django-2.2

I am trying to make a simple tg bot in python using django and pyTelegramBotApi, which is answering "Hello" on a /start. I've set webhook, and bot is getting updates correctly, but when it comes to send_message it just goes trough and sends nothing.

```
@csrf_exempt
def update_bot(request):
    json_str = request.body.decode("UTF-8")
    update = types.Update.de_json(json_str)
    tele_bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return HttpResponse({'code': 200})


@tele_bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    print("sending message")
    print(tele_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Hello"))
```

And the console output is

```
sending message
[24/Dec/2020 10:54:46] "POST /bot/imagesmanager/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved the issue. I have just read my token with \n at the end (found with `repr(token)`), idk why update worked properly, but simple strip helped me well enough)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the error is because the message is not being printed, but I have been using this: `https://api.telegram.org/{bot_id}/sendMessage` since a long time now and it works perfectly. The [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) is very informative on how to use the api in this form.

Comment: yea, i've tried using telegram's api and it works fine, but idk why send_message doesn't work at all:/

Comment: you might want to check your chat id, sometimes even a single character error causes a problem.

Comment: I did. Actually, i did take chat_id from my program to try to send message via tg api and as i said - it worked fine